# Navigation Controller .. Table view Background image

Tags: ios7, storyboard, uitableview

When I add a Navigation Controller, I have two views: A Navigation Controller and a Table View.

I want to add static cell in the Table view. The Table view class is `UITableViewController`. How can I add a background image to the `Table View Controller`?

I have no Class where I can write in the code. I am a Beginner in Xcode. Where can I add the code:

```
UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]];
[tableView setBackgroundView:bg];
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgJYk.png

or where there is an example?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a background image to a UITableViewControll from storyboard. What you have to do is create a custom class for your UITableViewControll and add the code in the ViewDidLoad method to add your background.

Create A Custom Class
dropbox.com/s/zqh5zu02f2dt0zo/create_custom_class.png

Assign your custom class to your Storyboard tableviewcontroller.
dropbox.com/s/5l94b9htfa1mz2w/add_custom_class.png

Add your code in the ViewDidLoad for your background image.
dropbox.com/s/2kz6m4iku27kyxz/code.png

Your app should now have a custom background behind the tableview.
dropbox.com/s/ks4riraqblaluoy/app.png

I hope that helps.